# UIWebView play video covered by other viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My app viewcontroller structure like this:

self.window.rootViewController = menuViewController;

A MainViewController covers menuViewController. And in MainViewController present a web view controller

```
[self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In this webViewController click a hyperlink open a video web page, click play button in this page, a full screen video play view flash and then disappear, I dismiss that present web view and move MainViewController out, found that the video page actually is cover upon menuViewController.

Two Questions:

1. How should I bring video play controller up to present web view?
2. When I click "Done" button in video play controller, get an exception. Feel like inherit issue. Show me how, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by set self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;

Why dosen't apple set the pop up video view controller to the top of exist views of window?